# Input required on Payments and Applications screen

Tags: acumatica

Could anyone please help me, at what scenario value in this "Due Date" field will be populated, .aspx looks like this, it is coming from SOOrder DAC.

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="SOOrder__DueDate" Label="Due Date" Width="90px" ></px:PXGridColumn>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The double underscore notation '__' is an Acumatica convention that means the field is coming from a joined DAC instead of the primary DAC of the DataView.

Using Acumatica [Inspect Element](https://www.timrodman.com/inspect-element-best-friend/) feature on the grid you can find the DataView name 'SOAdjustments' and use button Actions->View Business Logic Source... to get the DataView declaration:

```
PXSelectJoin<SOAdjust,

LeftJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<SOAdjust.adjdOrderType>,
                  And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOAdjust.adjdOrderNbr>>>>,

Where<SOAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<Current<ARPayment.docType>>,
      And<SOAdjust.adjgRefNbr, Equal<Current<ARPayment.refNbr>>>>> SOAdjustments;
```

The primary DAC of the DataView is the first DAC appearing in the BQL query: SOAdjust in this case.

In the LeftJoin BQL clauses the SOOrder DAC is joined to the query. DueDate field displayed on screen is the joined SOOrder DAC of that query.

SOOrder.DueDate field resolves to the DueDate field of the SOOrder database table. It's a standard DB field which means the value displayed is simply taken from the database.

In your case I believe the value is initially set by the [Terms(…)] attribute on SOOrder.TermsID field:

```
#region TermsID
public abstract class termsID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected String _TermsID;
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<Customer.termsID, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Terms", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Terms.termsID, Where<Terms.visibleTo, Equal<TermsVisibleTo.all>, Or<Terms.visibleTo, Equal<TermsVisibleTo.customer>>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(Terms.descr), Filterable = true)]
[Terms(typeof(SOOrder.invoiceDate), typeof(SOOrder.dueDate), typeof(SOOrder.discDate), typeof(SOOrder.curyOrderTotal), typeof(SOOrder.curyTermsDiscAmt))]
public virtual String TermsID
{
    get
    {
        return this._TermsID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._TermsID = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

The algorithm to compute DueDate is part of PX.Objects.CS.TermsAttribute.CalcTermsDates method:

```
public static void CalcTermsDates(Terms terms, DateTime? docDate, out DateTime? dueDate, out DateTime? discDate)
{
    dueDate = null;
    discDate = null;
    if (docDate != null && terms != null)
    {
        DateTime DocDate = docDate.Value;
        switch (terms.DueType)
        {
            case TermsDueType.FixedNumberOfDays:
                dueDate = DocDate.AddDays((double)terms.DayDue00);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Prox:
                DateTime sameDayOfNextMonth = DocDate.AddMonths(1);
                DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(sameDayOfNextMonth.Year, sameDayOfNextMonth.Month, 1);
                dueDate = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays((double)terms.DayDue00);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth:
                dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfTheMonth:
                int monthShift = DocDate.Day > (int)terms.DayDue00 ? 1 : 0;
                dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(monthShift);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Custom:
                int nextmonth = 0;
                if (DocDate.Day >= terms.DayFrom00 && DocDate.Day <= terms.DayTo00)
                {
                    if (terms.DayDue00 <= terms.DayTo00)
                    {
                        nextmonth = 1;
                    }
                    dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(nextmonth);
                }
                if (DocDate.Day >= terms.DayFrom01 && DocDate.Day <= terms.DayTo01)
                {
                    if (terms.DayDue01 <= terms.DayTo01)
                    {
                        nextmonth = 1;
                    }
                    dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue01).AddMonths(nextmonth);
                }
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfMonth:
                dueDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth:
                dueDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (terms.InstallmentType == TermsInstallmentType.Multiple)
        {
            discDate = dueDate;
        }
        else
        {
        switch (terms.DiscType)
        {
            case TermsDueType.FixedNumberOfDays:
                discDate = DocDate.AddDays((double)terms.DayDisc);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Prox:
                DateTime sameDayOfNextMonth = DocDate.AddMonths(1);
                DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(sameDayOfNextMonth.Year, sameDayOfNextMonth.Month, 1);
                discDate = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays((double)terms.DayDisc);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth:
                discDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDisc).AddMonths(1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfTheMonth:
                int monthShift;

                    if (terms.DueType == TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth && DocDate.Day <= (int)terms.DayDue00)
                        monthShift = DocDate.Day >= (int)terms.DayDisc ? 1 : 0;
                else if (terms.DueType == TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth)
                    monthShift = DocDate.Day >= (int)terms.DayDisc ? 1 : 0;
                else
                    monthShift = DocDate.Day > (int)terms.DayDue00 ? 1 : 0;
                discDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDisc).AddMonths(monthShift);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfMonth:
                discDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth:
                discDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        }

        if (discDate > dueDate)
        {
            discDate = dueDate;
        }
    }           
}
```